# Maven-compiler-plugin throws wanted compile errors but deny the compile progress

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, compilation

A few days ago i started with Maven. I have to put only a few of my dependencies in my generated jar file. This is needed because my code is only a plugin (Minecraft Plugin) executed by an api (Minecraft Server Software Spigot). Now the Problem is, that my Plugin depends on an other api (json-simple-1.1).

The last days i tried to edit the maven shade plugin to get the wished result. I failed, and now i did it in this way:

- maven include the json-simple-1.1 api, i needing for my plugin
- eclipse include the spigot api (Minecraft server software), which will executing my plugin

pom.xml:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.falco.essentialsXXX</groupId>
  <artifactId>EssentialsXXX-bungeecord</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Basic class for every Plugin
</description>
  <build>
  
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    
    <!-- COMPILE -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      
      <!-- BUILD -->
      
      <plugin>
      
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        
        <configuration>
        
        
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-json</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        
        </configuration>
        
        <executions>
        
            <execution>
            
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            
            </execution>
        
        </executions>
      
      </plugin>
      
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
  <dependencies>
  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  
  </dependencies>
  
</project>
```

When i now execute 'mvn clean install' (in the right directory) i get many many errors. That make completely sense. Maven can not find types or classes and everything else comeing from the spigot-api.
My Problem is, that this isnt a real error because when the spigot-api execute my plugin i have the classes and types i need. Maven dont know that and dont compile my Programm :(
At this point a have no idea what to do. I read so many articles but i couldnt find a solution. Every article say ohhh an error here try to use  tags and the right api values. That isnt what i need.

I need something like a "bypass" attribute for the compiler so the compiler know "yes this is an error but the coder knows what he does"

Comment: You shoud add the dependency to the spigot api in the pom.xml. It seems the artifact is not in the Maven central repository, but there is a separate repository that you can also add in the pom.xml. Check this wiki article: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-maven/

Comment: i dont know what your point is. I couldnt edit the pom.xml from the spigot api. And i also couldnt add the spigot dependencie/repository to my pom.xml because i dont want to put the spigot.jar in my generated jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need something for compilation, it needs to be a Maven dependency.

So take that artifact, install it in your local repository and add it as dependency.

Then your compilation process will probably work.

Note that using a dependency does not mean that you have to include the dependency into the resulting jar.

Comment: "Note that using a dependency does not mean that you have to include the dependency into the resulting jar." how should i do this?

Comment: You can configure the descriptor of the maven assembly plugin, or use the maven shade plugin instead.